# New to Python: Turtle 25 squares checkerboard using loops

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

```
def main():
    square(0,0,50,'red')


def square(x,y,width,color):  

    turtle.penup()  
    turtle.goto(0,0)  
    turtle.fillcolor(color)  
    turtle.pendown()  
    turtle.begin_fill()

    for number in range(5):
        for count in range(4):
            turtle.forward(width)
            turtle.left(90)
        turtle.end_fill()
        x = x+50
        turtle.goto(x,y)


    turtle.showturtle()
```

Call the main function

```
main()
```

This gives me one row of 5 squares. How do i code an outer loop to draw 4 more 
of rows of such 5 squares - a 5 by 5 checkerboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified your "square" function to only draw a single square. Then I added a separate function which included a nested loop that calls the square function. 
Trying to keep it simple and have only one responsibility for each function:

```
import turtle

def main():
    board(5, 5, 50)
    input("Hit enter to close")

def square(x,y,width,color):
    turtle.penup()  
    turtle.fillcolor(color)  
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.begin_fill()
    for side in range(4):
        turtle.forward(width)
        turtle.left(90)
    turtle.end_fill()

def board(rows, columns, square_width):
    turtle.showturtle()
    for row in range(rows):
        for column in range(columns):
            color = "red" if (row + column)%2 == 1 else "white"
            square(row*square_width, column*square_width, square_width, color)
    turtle.hideturtle()
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have code to draw a row of squares, that's the loop you have right now.

You want that code to be run 5 times, so just wrap it in another loop, making sure to modify variables as necessary. Something along the lines of this:

```
for i in range(5):  
    for number in range(5):
        for count in range(4):
            turtle.forward(width)
            turtle.left(90)
        turtle.end_fill()
        x += width
        turtle.goto(x,y)
    x -= 5*width
    y += width
```

Also a note on style, `square()` is ignoring most of its parameters. You hardcode your turtle to go to (0,0), regardless of the values of `x` and `y`. Because your later `goto`s use these values, your code will break if you set them to anything other than 0. Your line `x = x+50` also ignores the value of `width`, even though the line the turtle draws uses it. Again, if you set it to anything other than 50, this will break.